# What does a car sound like when it’s starting?

Tags: onomatopoeia

If you put your foot on the gas when starting the engine, it's definitely 'vroom'. Each increase in revs gets a vroom of it's own (three squeezes of the pedal, "vroom vroom vroom").

If I were asked to mimic a starting car, I'd try something like "v-v-v-vroom!"). So, I think va-va-voom can apply to starting an engine as much as revving it...

Comment: You meant `of its own`.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with vroom, not va-va voom, because of the dictionary definition.

va-va-voom
in British English
(ˌvæˌvæˈvuːm )
NOUN
informal
the quality of being interesting, exciting, or sexually appealing

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/va-va-voom

Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Another reason why: we say an engine “purrs”. A purr, by definition, is a vibrating noise or hum. “Vroom” definitely is a vibration, but not va-va voom.

2. VERB
   When the engine of a machine such as a car purrs, it is working and making a quiet, continuous, vibrating sound.
   Both boats purred out of the cave mouth and into open water. [VERB preposition]
   The sleek car purred down the country road. [VERB preposition]
   [Also VERB]
   Purr is also a noun.
   Carmela heard the purr of a motor-cycle coming up the drive. [+ of]
   https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/purr
   Hope that helps.

Comment: *va-va-voom in British English (ˌvæˌvæˈvuːm ) NOUN informal the quality of being interesting, exciting, or sexually appealing* surely entirely applicable to the starting note of a car engine, or at least to the hoped-for note!